# Styling views table - Toogle row class on click

Tags: views, javascript, theming

I have a view which is shown as table. I would like to add a css class to entire row, once the user has clicked somewhere on the row.

With views i added '.baza-pregled-strank-row' class to each row. Below is my jquery code, which is successfully loaded, but not doing what it should, because once i click on the view-field, the class is not aded to the row. Big thanks.

```
(function ($) {
$('.view-field').on('click', function(e) {
      $('.baza-pregled-strank-row').toggleClass("highlight");
      e.preventDefault();
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: See [Managing JavaScript in Drupal 7](https://drupal.org/node/756722), especially [Behaviors](https://drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors) section. It seems that your problem may be with the way you include your js file, with the fact you are not using behaviors, or possibly many more, probably already covered in linked piece of documentation.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to add custom class to your VIEWS wrapper and also for TABLE ROW.
I have added `my-view-wrapper` for the VIEWS and `row-wrapper` for TABLE ROW

[image]

- Add CLASS to your VIEWS

  [image]
- Add CLASS to your TABLE ROW

  [image]

  [image]

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.viewRowHighlight = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $('.my-view-wrapper .row-wrapper').click(function(e){
        $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I tried doing what you suggested but it does not work, besides firebug console shows the error below

SyntaxError: function statement requires a name
 

attach: function (context, settings) {

Comment: Are you using Drupal 7?

Comment: Yes i am, the newest version.

Comment: There's an error in your javascript inizio. I corrected it. @rishariss copy the javascript code and try again.

Comment: I have updated my code you can check it out.

Answer (score 0):

The class Views adds to the fields is called views-field. This code would toggle the class hightlight for each field (cell) in the table.

```
Drupal.behaviors.highlightViewsField = {
  attach: function (context) {
    $('.views-field').on('click', function(e) {
      $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
    });
  }
}
```

If you want to toggle the row you would do something like

```
Drupal.behaviors.highlightViewsRow = {
  attach: function (context) {
    $('.view-content tr').on('click', function(e) {
      $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Without [behaviors](https://drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors) this is a simple way to make user ask "why does it fail half of the times?" pretty soon.

Comment: does not work. I belive that the targeted class for click event thould be view-field since row is made of view-fields which take all the space and the row should be targeted for adding new class to it.

Comment: Thanks Molot, I've updated the answer with Drupal.behaviours.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the documentation that Mołot suggested and managed to make it work. Below is the code with dummy classes, targeting the views row inside views wrapper. Thanks for all the help guys.

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.views_row_highlight = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $('.views-table-wrapper .views-table-row', context).click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```